# How to set column's comment with CREATE TABLE and SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

I want to set column's comment with CREATE TABLE and SELECT statement in MySQL(MySQL version is 5.1.69.).
I try the following query. However column's comment is not set.

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  parent_id INT(10) NULL COMMENT 'test'
) ENGINE=INNODB 
SELECT 1 AS parent_id;

SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM t;

+-----------+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field     | Type    | Collation | Null | Key | Default | Extra | Privileges                      | Comment |
+-----------+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| parent_id | int(10) | NULL      | YES  |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
+-----------+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How do I set column's comment with CREATE TABLE and SELECT statement.

Comment: What does the `SELECT` statement have to do with your table creation? Why is it important / what significance does it have?

Comment: In fact the portion of the `SELECT` statement, it adds to insert the records that match the condition from other table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom comment using `CREATE TABLE .... SELECT` seems not possible.

Documentation on [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-select.html) does only specify that the parent comments are retained. It did not mention anything if an in line new comment is defined using `create ... select` syntax, what the behaviour is.

> *Retrained attributes are `NULL` (or `NOT NULL`) and, for those columns that have them, `CHARACTER SET, COLLATION, COMMENT`, and the `DEFAULT` clause*

Following observations say that that the new custom `comment` being tried on new column is ignored.

And if you still want to re-define your own comment, you have to use `alter table` command to add on the newly created table column.

**Example**:

```
mysql> create table tbl_so_q23798048_1( i int not null comment 'parent comment' );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.41 sec)

mysql> select table_name, column_name, column_comment
    ->   from information_schema.columns
    ->  where table_schema='so' and length(column_comment)>0;
+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| table_name         | column_name | column_comment  |
+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| tbl_so_q23798048_1 | i           | parent comment  |
+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Now, try to create a table based on the previously created table but with custom comment.

```
mysql> create table tbl_so_q23798048_2( i int comment 'custom comment' )
    ->     as select i from tbl_so_q23798048_1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.42 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select table_name, column_name, column_comment
    ->   from information_schema.columns
    ->  where table_schema='so' and length(column_comment)>0;
+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| table_name         | column_name | column_comment  |
+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| tbl_so_q23798048_1 | i           | parent comment  |
| tbl_so_q23798048_2 | i           | parent comment  |
+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

You can clearly see that custom comment is ignored.

Now, try with no custom comment on the new table's column.

```
mysql> create table tbl_so_q23798048_3( i int )
    ->     as select i from tbl_so_q23798048_1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.35 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select table_name, column_name, column_comment
    ->   from information_schema.columns
    ->  where table_schema='so' and length(column_comment)>0;
+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| table_name         | column_name | column_comment  |
+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| tbl_so_q23798048_1 | i           | parent comment  |
| tbl_so_q23798048_2 | i           | parent comment  |
| tbl_so_q23798048_3 | i           | parent comment  |
+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

You can see that parent comment is retained.
Now, you can alter the new table's column to add custom comment.

```
mysql> alter table tbl_so_q23798048_3
    ->       modify column i int comment 'custom comment';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select table_name, column_name, column_comment
    ->   from information_schema.columns
    ->  where table_schema='so' and length(column_comment)>0;
+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| table_name         | column_name | column_comment  |
+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| tbl_so_q23798048_1 | i           | parent comment  |
| tbl_so_q23798048_2 | i           | parent comment  |
| tbl_so_q23798048_3 | i           | custom comment  |
+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

And, you can't define new comment though the table column being selected does not have a `comment` on it.

```
mysql> create table tbl_so_q23798048_4( i int );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.68 sec)

mysql> create table tbl_so_q23798048_5( i int comment 'new comment' )
    -> as select i from tbl_so_q23798048_4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select table_name, column_name, column_comment
    ->   from information_schema.columns
    ->  where table_schema='so' and length(column_comment)>0
    ->    and table_name in ( 'tbl_so_q23798048_4', 'tbl_so_q23798048_5' );
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you. I understood behaviour of the `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`. I will redefine the column comment with `ALTER TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that `SELECT 1 AS parent_id;` from `create table` query. See a demo fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc46e1/1

your `CREATE TABLE` query should look like

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  parent_id INT(10) NULL COMMENT 'test'
) ENGINE=INNODB
```

**EDIT:**

Yes you can but if you are defining a new column in `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ...` example as below. if you say this then comment will be same as original table

```
CREATE TABLE t1
as
select parent_id from t;
```

But if you define a new column then you will get a new column comment. See a update fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44567/1

```
CREATE TABLE t2(id int null comment 'NEW TEST')
as
select parent_id from t;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. To set column's comment with `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` statement is impossible?

Comment: @hiro, Yes you can. See edited answer. don't forget to accept the answer if it helped.